# I cannot read the data from file it gives me nothing in php?

Tags: php, file

I am trying to write/read data to a file, when I start the page I remove the file and create a new file:

```
unlink("t.txt");
$myfile = fopen("t.txt", "w+");
```

then I write data to file using the following:

```
file_put_contents('t.txt', $number.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

then I try to read each line of the file as the following:

```
$lines = file("t.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
```

There is data in the file but the problem is the I get nothing on my screen, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Any errors about reading the file or being able to access it in the error log?

Comment: It seems strange to use file_put_contents while the file is open. That seems like it might cause problems. Can you do that before you open it instead? Wait, you're getting the contents with file(), so you don't really need to fopen() at all. file_put_contents should create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Adam No there is no errors

Comment: @Don'tPanic actually if I did not create file using fopen I am getting error the file is not exist, and it is all working except the reading just nothing

Comment: Which line gives the nonexistent file error? `file_get_contents()` or `file()`?

Comment: error is at file()

Comment: So it seems the file_put_contents failed. You can verify that by checking if it returns false. Out of curiosity, does it work without the lock?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the contents aren't ever written to the file.

The reason I've come to that conclusion: you have opened a file with a write lock on it, then you are trying to write to the same file using a different set of file access functions.

Consistency is key: if you want to use `fopen`, you should also use `fwrite`, and the rest of that set of commands (`fclose` when you are done, `fread` for reading a stream, etc).

Alternatively, use `file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents`, and `file` (as well as a few others) to avoid using streams. Personally, I prefer these for normal text files, but they can be costly for anything too large. Streams are great when dealing with large files or files that aren't text.

Probable solution to your problem: remove the `fopen` line.

The other potential cause could be down to access permissions. Might be best to do some further diagnosis if my solution above doesn't work for you.

Comment: They did say there's data in the file, though. So it must have been put there since they destroy the file at the beginning of the script. Well, unless it is a permission issue as you suggested, and it's never getting deleted

Comment: I tried to remove fopen and get error that file is not exist, so I need it to create the file after removing it, and the data is written to the file correctly but I am failing to read it, I get no errors, nothing. I tried to use file_get_contents and same result.